# ActivityNotFoundException but already declared in the Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

HY!

I always get the ActivityNotFound Error, but i already have my Activity declared in the Manifest.

Whats wrong?

Error:

```
10-17 20:28:24.881: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2141): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.korn.supplierplan/com.korn.supplierplan.view.LVEntries}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.korn.supplierplan"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET"> </uses-permission>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".view.Login"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".view.LVEntries"></activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Calling:

```
Intent i  = new Intent (Login.this,LVEntries.class);
i.putExtra("JSON", array.toString());
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Please share your both files packages you are currently using. You don't have to share whole class rather from packages to class extending Activity..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how you are naming the Activities in you Manifest file.

I'm guessing your class files are named `Login.java` not `view.Login.java`, am I right? If so change this:

```
    <activity android:name=".view.Login"  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

To This

```
    <activity android:name="Login"  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Do the same for `LVEntries`

If they are named like `view.Login.java` then remove the prepended `view.` in the name.

Comment: doesn't worked.... my logic is in the package com.korn.supplierplan and the views are in com.korn.supplierplan.view

Comment: Then change the package in your manifest file to com.korn.supplierplan.view, or move them from the .view subgroup.

Comment: the problem was the eclipse didn't overwrite my changes in the manifest. strange bug